# How does go infer a parameter value in a function call?

Tags: go

I am fairly new to golang but with exp with other OOP languages (java's lambda as well).

How does the call `router.GET("/", baseHandler)` works when a parameter is not explicitly passed in baseHandler and 2nd argument in router.GET expects ...Handlers

```
package main
import "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
func baseHandler(c *gin.Context){
   c.JSON(200, gin.H{
       "message": "hello world",
   })
}
func main() {
   router := gin.Default()
   router.GET("/", baseHandler)
   router.Run()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Handler` is of type `HandlerFunc`, which is

```
type HandlerFunc func(*Context)
```

So `router.GET` is passed a function variable, the `baseHandler`. When the router calls `baseHandler`, it passes a `*Context` to it.

Comment: where does the router get the value of *Context to be passed in baseHandler and how?

Comment: It creates the context. You can look at the source code for gin to see how it does that.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can be used as values. `baseHandler` is not being passed *any* parameters because it is not being called.